# Casper js : Not able to login site using casper js

Tags: casperjs

I am scraping a site using PHP and I am able to login to site and scrape site data as well.
Now I have switched to Casper js but it is not allowing me to log in site.
Tried to use different user-agents and IP's as well, but couldn't get any success.

```
casper = require('casper').create();
casper.on('started', function () {
  this.page.customHeaders = {
    "User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0", 
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8",
  }
});
casper.start('https:somesite.com');

casper.then(function() {
    this.fill('form#J_Form', {
        'TPL_password':    '123',
        'TPL_username':    'xyz',
    }, true);
});
casper.wait(20000, function() {
    this.echo("I've waited for a 2 seconds.");
});
 casper.then(function() {
    casper.capture('Screeenshots/loginsuccessfully1.png');
  });
 casper.thenOpen('https://item.othersite.com/item.htm?id=538450584178', function() {
 this.echo(this.getHTML());
 });
casper.run(function() {
    this.echo('login successfully').exit();
});
```

any suggestions would be helpfull
thanks.

Comment: Can you provide link to website?

Comment: https://www.tmall.com/

Comment: And where should this form appear? It is never in the DOM...

Answer (score 0):

First I would suggest to use this to start your Casper:

```
casper = require('casper').create({
  verbose: true,
  logLevel: 'debug',
  viewportSize: {width: 1280, height: 800},
});
```

as it will provide you much more information regarding what is actually happening in the process.

To answer your question, at login.tmall.com the login is in the iframe, so you need to switch first to that iframe to fill the form. You can do that with this.

```
casper.then(function() {
  this.withFrame(0, function() {
    this.fill('form#J_Form', {
        'TPL_password':    '123',
        'TPL_username':    'xyz',
    }, true);
  });
});
```

Then combining this with your code, you have this

```
casper = require('casper').create({
  verbose: true,
  logLevel: 'debug',
  viewportSize: {width: 1280, height: 800},
});
casper.on('started', function () {
  this.page.customHeaders = {
    "User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0", 
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8",
  }
});
casper.start('https://login.tmall.com/', function() {
  this.capture('test.png');
});

casper.then(function() {
  this.withFrame(0, function() {
    this.fill('form#J_Form', {
        'TPL_password':    '123',
        'TPL_username':    'xyz',
    }, true);
  });
});
casper.wait(20000, function() {
    this.echo("I've waited for a 2 seconds.");
});
 casper.then(function() {
    casper.capture('Screeenshots/loginsuccessfully1.png');
  });
 casper.thenOpen('https://item.othersite.com/item.htm?id=538450584178', function() {
 this.echo(this.getHTML());
 });
casper.run(function() {
    this.echo('login successfully').exit();
});
```